# Search query redirect mod_rewrie

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I got the following setup in my httpd.conf:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule /([^/]+) /?page=$1

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} search=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) /%1? [R=301]
```

When user enters something in a search box like "help", the URL looks like the following:

> domain.com/help

Works like a charm.

But if the user enters something again  in a search box like "forum", the URL will look like:

> domain/help?search=forum

I have am missing something. I would like all search queries to be:

> domain.com/{SEARCH_CRITERIA}

Comment: You indeed missed something: how rewriting actually works. Rewriting rules cannot change how a url is constructed by some scripting or ajax logic. That is up to the logic of the search solution, whatever you use. Rewriting rules can only change how the incoming url is interpreted on the server, but not on the client, unless you do a redirection. A redirection would change the clients location bar content, but only as a second step. And: what is the point in that?

Comment: it looks clean. Rather than _domain.com/?search=help_ the URL looks like _domain.com/help_. I just like how easy it looks in the URL bar, clean for bookmarking and easy for those users who care.

Comment: I _guess_ with your comment you refer to my closing question? Or do you want to express that things _already_ do look clean? If the first, then take a look into the excellent documentation and look for "redirection" (the [R] flag): http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: thank you for your help:) I appreciate it and will read up on the documentation:) I appreciate your time and effort to help me:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change order of rules and have 301 before other rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule /([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```